# CMS Magnolia magnolia-rest-content-delivery version in pom

Tags: rest, maven, magnolia

I need to install magnolia-rest-content-delivery module in Maven.

- Before installing this module I had following dependencies. Project was built and installed without problems.

[image]

Question: How it's possible not to define dependency version in magnolia projects?

- 1st attempt to install without version like others from group `info.magnolia.rest`

[image]

That cause error `[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for info.magnolia.rest:magnolia-rest-content-delivery:jar is missing.``

Question: What's so special about `magnolia-rest-content-delivery` so it does need version?

- 2nd attempt - add version to

[image]

That cause error during deployment

```
Module Magnolia REST Content Delivery (version 2.0.1) is dependent on rest-integration (version 2.0.1/*),
but Magnolia REST Integration (version 1.2.1) is currently installed.
```

- 3rd attempt: adding same version to all dependencies in `info.magnolia.rest` groupId

[image]

That cause same error during deployment

```
Module Magnolia REST Content Delivery (version 2.0.1) is dependent on rest-integration (version 2.0.1/*), 
but Magnolia REST Integration (version 1.2.1) is currently installed.
```

What can I try next to resolve issue?
Thank you.

Update:
Project's pom have dependency from magnolia-enterprise-bundle-parent v#5.5.4

[image]

in dependency tree I can see that `magnolia-rest-integration` picked-up version 1.2.1

[image]

What would be safe way to override version defined in BOM?

Update 2:

I end-up with overriding dependency versions in dependencyManagement section

[image]

Clean local maven repository and build

Regardles that effective pom now shows correct versions for magnolia rest modules result is almost the same

```
[ERROR] Module Magnolia REST Tools (version 2.0.1) is dependent on rest-integration (version 2.0.1/*), 
but Magnolia REST Integration (version 1.2.1) is currently installed.
[ERROR] Module Magnolia REST Content Delivery (version 2.0.1) is dependent on rest-integration (version 2.0.1/*), 
but Magnolia REST Integration (version 1.2.1) is currently installed.
```

I couldn't attach dependency tree output file (here is small excerpt)

```
[INFO] +- info.magnolia.eebundle:magnolia-enterprise-standard-webapp:war:5.5.4:compile
[INFO] +- info.magnolia.rest:magnolia-rest-integration:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- info.magnolia.core:magnolia-configuration:jar:5.5.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.atteo:evo-inflector:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:jar:3.0.19.SP1-redhat-1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation:jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final-redhat-1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final-redhat-1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jackson2-provider:jar:3.0.19.SP1-redhat-1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.8.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:jar:2.8.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.8.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxb-provider:jar:3.0.19.SP1-redhat-1:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile
[INFO] +- info.magnolia.rest:magnolia-rest-services:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.jackrabbit:jackrabbit-jcr-commons:jar:2.12.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jackson-provider:jar:3.0.19.SP1-redhat-1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.9.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.9.12:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-client:jar:3.0.19.SP1-redhat-1:compile
[INFO] +- info.magnolia.rest:magnolia-rest-tools:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-jaxrs:jar:1.5.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.8.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:jar:2.8.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.swagger:swagger-core:jar:1.5.4:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:jar:2.8.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.4:compile
[INFO] +- info.magnolia.rest:magnolia-rest-content-delivery:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.json:javax.json-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish:javax.json:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.jackrabbit:jackrabbit-spi-commons:jar:2.12.4:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.jackrabbit:jackrabbit-spi:jar:2.12.4:compile
```

The only place where this mistic "Magnolia REST Integration (version 1.2.1)" mentioned is:

.m2\repository\info\magnolia\bundle\magnolia-bundle-parent\5.5.4\magnolia-bundle-parent-5.5.4.pom

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Version numbers for rest comes from parent pom that you most likely extend or from dependency section of Magnolia CE or EE webapp that you import or from BOM. No way to say w/o seeing whole pom. As for what's special about Content Delivery - it's not defined in the "source" of versions for other modules hence you need to declare it explicitly.
From the error it most likely looks like you end up with both versions of the artefact in your webapp or version is not being picked up (i.e. some error in your pom). You should not need to declare `magnolia-rest-integration` at all as it should be pulled in by either `magnolia-rest-content-delivery` or by `-services` or `-tools` modules anyway.

Please include link to whole pom. Also please provide output of running `mvn dependency:tree` to point out exactly what is wrong.

Comment: Thank you Jan. 1) You are right I can exclude rest-integration. 2)Project's pom have dependency from magnolia-enterprise-bundle-parent v#5.5.4. I've updated original post.

Comment: Tryed to override dependency version. Update in origoinal post. Thank you.

Comment: Alexei please post whole output of dependency tree on pastebin.com or gist and just link it here. Without seeing whole output we can't figure out where is the dependency coming from. Your excerpt only shows that it's not coming from rest modules, which is expected. thx.

Comment: Tried to reproduce your problem, but all works fine - see parent pom: https://gist.github.com/rah003/30c6a52749563c7f5774a6a66c89ca34 and war file pom: https://gist.github.com/rah003/85ba9d73703aec29f6eb7efaafbb511d

Comment: Hi Jan. I realize that Magnolia 5.5.4. has Rest version 1.2.1 and have not mention for content-delivery module support. Thank you.

Comment: Ohhh. You did it! Thank you. Let me try.

Comment: I have same error message. Here is mvn tree output https://gist.github.com/JavaPantry/2b4b4d66e2f32e5740db2d36f7f9a9ca